# Continue is not inside a loop

Tags: exception, compiler-errors, d

I was writing a method for TCPServer. I've written a code as below:

```
    // thread run
protected void threadRun(){
    // continue running. don't stop
    while(true){
        try{
            try{
            }
            catch(Exception e1){
                try{
                } catch(Exception e2){}
                finally{
                    // skip
                    continue;
                }
            }
        }
        catch(Exception e3){
        }
    }
}
```

Content is not important. There were codes to accept client etc, but I have removed them to make sure about that it is not about details. Anyway, when I try to compile this code, compiler says for that `continue` line:

`Error: continue is not inside a loop`

By thinking that maybe I know it wrong, I've written the complete same code in Java as seen below:

```
class test{
public static void main(String[] args){
    while(true){
        try{
            try{
            }
            catch(Exception e1){
                try{
                } catch(Exception e2){}
                finally{
                    continue;
                }
            }

        }
        catch(Exception e3){
        }
    }
}
}
```

As I expected, java compiler doesn't give any error message and compiles successfully. What exactly can the problem be?

Comment: I guess there must be some mistake in the code you've skipped here now. sounds silly but perhaps you forgot to close a brace!Or maybe a redundant brace.

Comment: I have copied same code, and pasted into Java's main method, and there is no error message on compilation.

Comment: what if you use a labeled continue?

Comment: http://forum.dlang.org/thread/simimruzgmuhfqjlpvxm@forum.dlang.org , sounds strange but seems like D language doesn't support breaking out of nested scopes unless you explicitly declare of which loop you want to jump out,using labels. and ofcourse the same thing may hold for continue as well.

Comment: There is only one loop in the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently, `continue` (and `break`) can't break out of a `finally` block. Compiling this:

```
void run() {
loop:
    while (true) {
        try {}
        catch (Exception e) {}
        finally {
            continue loop;
        }
    }
}
```

will give you this (omitting the label gives the same error you got):

```
Error: cannot continue out of finally block
```

I haven't yet found a justification or explanation of this restriction (**edit:** see ratchet freak's comment below). However, I can't imagine it's a super-common use case. You probably want to look at other options.

Comment: finally can happen when there is an exception, D doesn't allow interrupting exception handling in `finally`s by moving out of the finally (like java would)

Comment: I tried the same code on Visual C# now, and it says "Control cannot leave the body of a finally clause". Either error code is written wrongly in DMD compiler, or semantic analyser is converting the code in a different way, thus it understands it differently. Anyway I used a boolean variable to solve the problem.